# How to set a theme when knitting RMarkdown to HTML?

Tags: html, r, highlight, knitr, r-markdown

I have not been able to figure out how to set a knitr theme when converting RMarkdown to HTML.
I have tried code such as

```
> opts_knit$set(out.format = "html")
> opts_chunk$set(highlight = TRUE)
> knit_theme$set("olive")
```

That does not affect the html output. I have tried this code before knitting the `Rmd` file as well as inside the first chunk.

Comment: `knit_theme` only applies to straight HTML and LaTeX output. Markdown and all other types of output are not relevant. You have to understand CSS; see Dieter's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a css file with the same name as your R file, but extension css, into the directory.

Or see
http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know anything about css. I'm looking for a convenient way using `knit_theme`.

Comment: Moreover this link provides some ways using the `markdownToHTML` function but just today I have encountered two bugs with this function when using MathJax https://github.com/rstudio/markdown/issues?state=open