# How do I style code in Rmarkdown for HTML?

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I want to change the style of the code for HTML output. The ideal way would be to use `knit_theme$set()` but that doesn't work for HTML.

Is there a way to style the code easily? Or otherwise, how do I access the elements? The background can be change via

```
.main-content pre {
  background-color:
}
```

but what about `num`, `str`, `com`, `opt`, `std`, `kwa`, `kwb`, `kwc`, `kwd`?

Comment: Have you seen the below? This should help some! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288379/how-to-set-a-theme-when-knitting-rmarkdown-to-html

Comment: @Frewtea This doesn't apply here. See the answer in the post you linked.